# Mechanical energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction

an object is sliding down a ramp. As the object slides, friction acts on the object. Which statement must be true?

a) the mechanical energy of the object is increasing

b)the mechanical energy of the object is decreasing

c)the mechanical energy of the object remains the same

d)either a or c is possible

e) either b or c is possible

I believe that the answer is: mechanical energy is decreasing, because mechanical energy is not conserved. friction is action on the object, which means kinetic energy is being transferred to thermal energy. am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanical energy is always constant if the system is conservative. A system is conservative if there are no external forces like frictions and in this case we have the friction with the ramp. So we can say thar the mechanic energy, that is kinetic energy and potential energy, is decreasing while the object moves.